# Is the ADM Mass for a boosted black hole $M$ or $\gamma M$?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, mass-energy, lorentz-symmetry

If you were to take the metric for a Schwarzschild black hole and "boost" it, such that it were traveling with velocity $v$, would the ADM mass, corresponding to a time translation, be $M$ or $\gamma M$, where $\gamma = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2} }$?

If this were the case, maybe "ADM energy" would be a better name than "ADM mass."

Comment: Yes, ADM is the energy (relative to the arbitrary frame fixed at infinity), not exactly the "mass".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What ADM defined was an energy-momentum vector, which can be interpreted as the energy-momentum vector of an isolated object in the frame of reference of a distant observer. (The notion of a distant observer only makes sense because we assume an asymptotically flat spqcetime.) This energy-momentum vector transforms as you would expect, so yes, the energy component becomes $\gamma M$ if you're not in the rest frame of the object. The ADM mass can be defined as the norm of this four-vector.  For a more detailed discussion of this, see Wald, p. 293. The sentence that explicitly answers your question is the one beginning with "Furthermore, the Einstein evolution equations..."

Comment: The ADM mass is the norm of the ADM 4-momentum.

Answer (score 0):

In an asymptotically flat spacetime the ADM energy is formulated as an integral over a two-sphere at spatial infinity. The metric is written as $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$, where $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric and $h_{\mu \nu}$ is assumed to be small at spatial infinity. If $h_{\mu \nu}$ is time-independent at infinity, the ADM energy agrees with the Komar energy (associated to the timelike Killing vector), which in turn matches with a Schwarzschild mass/energy.

However both Komar and Schwarzschild refer to a massive object at the origin of the coordinates. In your question you think of a boost for the black hole and then you assume the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ of special relativity. As in a curved manifold a global inertial reference frame does not exist, I do not think that your reasoning is applicable.

Note: In general relativity mass means energy, that is rest mass + kinetic energy + interacting energy of the constituents of an object.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question one way or the other. *As in a curved manifold a global inertial reference frame does not exist, I do not think that your reasoning is applicable.* It's not clear to me what conclusion you're drawing here, but this doesn't seem right. The ADM mass is defined in an asymptotically flat spacetime, so we do have an inertial reference frame associated with a distant observer.

Comment: @Ben Crowell. I agree that there is an inertial reference frame associated to a distant observer, but it is not a global frame. Do you mean that another distant observer in relative motion experiences a mass of $\gamma M$ instead of $M$? That is not how for instance the path of a free falling particle is described in Schwarzschild spacetime. The curvature is assumed to be given by $M$ independently of the velocity of the particle.