Does speed affect gravitational force according to special relativity?
According to the special relativity, when the speed of an object increases, its mass also increases. Does it mean that objects moving at speeds close to the speed of light exert higher gravitational force to the objects nearby? If yes, what would be the gravitational formula?
Can we inspect this situation in the boundaries of special relativity or do we have to switch to general relativity?
Note: I have checked suggested questions but did not come up with a similar one.

Just as an aside, the faster the object, the more it is gravitated. I mean, neutrinos are deflected by the Sun according to general relativity -- twice the Newtonian prediction. Good luck with the answers that you get. I'm very interested in the answer.

This question is similar to: If a mass moves close to the speed of light, does it turn into a black hole?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Gravitation is the one case whereby everybody agrees that you cannot use SR to get answers for. You can use SR to work with accelerations due to all other forces.

possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693723/

There is no theory of gravity compatible with Special Relativity that works. You need General Relativity, which leads to the Einstein-Infeld-Hoffmann equations for gravitational force. They show the effect of velocity.

According to the special relativity, when the speed of an object increases, its mass also increases. Its relativistic mass does, but its invariant mass doesn’t. Relativistic mass is an obsolete concept that even Einstein considered a mistake. Today “mass” means invariant mass to most physicists.


Does it mean that objects moving at speeds close to the speed of light exert higher gravitational force to the objects nearby? If yes, what would be the gravitational formula?

Special relativity cannot be used for analyzing situations where tidal gravity is substantial. General relativity must be used instead.
In General Relativity the gravitation of an object is not a function of mass, but rather it depends on the stress energy tensor. The stress energy tensor involves the energy, momentum, pressure, and stress.
In the Newtonian limit all of the other terms are negligible except for the energy. But as you consider a reference frame where the object is moving at relativistic velocities then the momentum terms are also not negligible. So the gravitation of such an object cannot simply be described as solely due to the energy. In rough terms the momentum effects roughly cancel out the energy terms such that things like orbits are consistent in all frames.

Thank you for the answer. I have two separate questions. 1. Why do we mention mass in special relativity then? To stick to F=m*a? Maybe we need to discard this formula? 2. You said: "In rough terms the momentum effects roughly cancel out the energy terms". Does this mean "momentum contributes as negative gravity in general relativity"?

@Xfce4 rest mass is a perfectly sensible concept in SR. It has a meaning outside of gravitation.

@Xfce4 as naturallyInconsistent said, mass is a perfectly valid concept in SR. Gravity is not the only use of mass. You already mentioned Newton’s 2nd law. It is also a conserved relativistic invariant of a system of particles, so that is useful. “Negative gravity” doesn’t really make sense because gravity is a tensor and you cannot describe tensors as positive or negative.

@Dale Thank you. What I meant is, do we assume mass changes with speed because this assumption makes F=ma hold. Maybe there is a hidden parameter in F=ma which we interpret it as a mass increase while what actually happens is different.

@Xfce4 physicists don’t assume that mass changes with speed, and we have not assumed that for nearly a century now. Unfortunately the outdated concept of relativistic mass is still in lots of pop-sci stuff, but working physicists use invariant mass including in the relativistic version of Newton’s 2nd law. Mass is a conserved and invariant quantity, as I mentioned above

@Dale If physicists don't assume mass changes with speed do they assume acceleration in F = ma changes with speed ? How do they explain that speed of light cannot be breached with constant force?

@Xfce4 the key is to stop using non-relativistic geometry, especially non-relativistic vectors. If you use relativistic four-vectors, then the speed of light limitation falls out naturally from F=ma with the invariant mass m. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration

@Dale Thank you for your patience. I think by four relativistic vectors you mean velocity in space-time. Do you mean  "just assume velocity vector is shrinked at relativistic speeds" ? If no, could you please direct me to a source so that I do not waste your time.

@Xfce4 there is certainly a relativistic velocity called the four-velocity. There is also four-force, four-momentum, and many other relativistic quantities. Section 17.5 is a good start here https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/17%3A_Relativistic_Mechanics/17.05%3A_Geometry_of_Space-time Ben Crowell also has several relativity textbooks at different levels http://www.lightandmatter.com/books.html
